# Realm Query using result of MYSLQ query

Tags: android, mysql, realm

i need to create a Realm query (possibly asynchronous) to retrieve card's images from Realm database using IDs got from from a MYSQL Query to an online DB:
The problem is that to create a Realm query i need to write `query.equalTo("name", "John");` but i do not know how much cards an user have got so i can not use that type of query. How can i solve this? Thank you :)

My internet call to the online DB:

```
public void getCards() { //It is used when adapter is created, and it need to contain all cards to display

        //Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        String urlToGet = "myurl";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("user_name", user_name)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlToGet)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                }

                responseCardInInventory = response.body().string();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        List<CardInInv> cardListInInv = new ArrayList<>();

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        CardInInventory civ = gson.fromJson(responseCardInInventory, CardInInventory.class);
                        cardListInInv = getGsonCards(civ);

                        RealmQuery<Card> query = realm.where(Card.class);


                        //TODO EXECUTE REALM QUERY
                        //TODO HERE I NEED TO USE REALM TO EXECUTE A QUERY USING cardListInInv


                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: `i need to write query.equalTo("name", "John"); but i do not know how much cards an user have got so i can not use that type of query` what?

Comment: Sorry for my english, i mean that to create a query using Realm you need to specify an attribute, such as "name", and what it need to cointain to verify the query, such as "John". But i dont know how much, for example, "name" i need to check.

Comment: Why can't you just make a query like `realm.where(Card.class).equalTo("userName", user_name).findAllAsync()`?

Comment: I'm trying with this but it doesnt work:

`RealmQuery<Card> query = realm.where(Card.class);

                        for(int i = 0; i < cardListInInv.size(); i++)
                            query.equalTo("id",cardListInInv.get(i).getId_card());

                        RealmResults<Card> result = query.findAllSorted("rarity");

                        dataCard = result;`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, so I'll just give a generic answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sufficient information about your domain as specified in my comment, all I can specify is how the proper solution is supposed to look like.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadedPool(); // bg thread

    Realm realm;
    RealmResults<Card> results;
    RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Card>> realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Card>>() {
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Card> element) { // updates on Write
            adapter.setData(element); 
        }
    }

    MyAdapter adapter;


    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        results = realm.where(Card.class).equalTo("userId", user_name);
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);

        adapter = new MyAdapter();

        String urlToGet = "myurl";

        executor.post(new Runnable() { // TODO: cancellation
            @Override
            public void run() {

                OkHttpClient client = ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getOkHttpClient();

                Gson gson = ((CustomApplication)getApplication()).getGson();

                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("user_name", user_name)
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(urlToGet)
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();


                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                }            
                responseCardInInventory = response.body().string();

                CardInInventory civ = gson.fromJson(responseCardInInventory, CardInInventory.class);
                List<CardInInv> cardListInInv = getGsonCards(civ);

                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Card card = new Card();
                        for(CardInInv cardInInv: cardListInInv) {
                            // map inv to card
                        }
                        realm.insertOrUpdate(card);
                    }
                });
           }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    results.removeAllChangeListeners();
    results = null;
    realm.close();
}
```